# Pulumi commands not working after intruption

Tags: devops, cicd, pulumi

Interrupting `pulumi up` command caused below error

```
error: could not get cloud url: failed to read Pulumi credentials file. Please re-run `pulumi login` to reset your credentials file: unexpected end of JSON input
```

When trying to run `pulumi login` it gives below error

```
error: could not determine current cloud: failed to read Pulumi credentials file. Please re-run `pulumi login` to reset your credentials file: unexpected end of JSON input
```

Any idea how to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to corrupted credentials file, Run `which pulumi` and the credentials.json file in the installation directroy and delete it. Run `pulumi login`